# Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, ngx-translate

I am trying to use ngx-translate or ng2-translate for months now...

I keep let it go for a while and continue to develop other sections of the app.

I have tried again now with Core 2, but still no luck.

I create the project and it works perfectly. I can change or create Angular components with everything running great.

As soon as I install ngx-translate (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core) or ng2-translate(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate) nothing works. The most common problem that I encounter is

```
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Andrei\AngularDefault\SIGAD\node_modules\@angular\platform-server\bundles\platform-server.umd.js'.
```

I get these warnings when I install though:

npm install @ngx-translate/core --save

```
npm WARN aspnet-webpack@2.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^1.13.2 || ^2.1.0-beta but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-chai@0.1.0 requires a peer of chai@* but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-jasmine@1.1.0 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.11.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngx-translate/core@7.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any
"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

for npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader

```
npm WARN @ngx-translate/core@7.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN aspnet-webpack@2.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^1.13.2 || ^2.1.0-beta but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-chai@0.1.0 requires a peer of chai@* but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-jasmine@1.1.0 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.11.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngx-translate/http-loader@1.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=4.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngx-translate/http-loader@1.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=4.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any
"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

This is not the only file that I get with "Prerendering failed because...". For example, the strangest thing is if I download Mark Pieszak template https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal. I get another file in the error:

```
NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Andrei\AngularDefault\SIGAD\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js'
at Error (native)
```

Without me making any changes...is this a Windows problem or something?

From other questions and issues on github like [Ionic: Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994097/ionic-error-module-build-failed-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory)
 I suspect that after I have updated Angular to the newest version 4.3.6 some of the packages have changed their case, but I fail to find them.

I haven't event written code to use one of these packages...

my package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "SIGAD",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.6",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.6.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.5",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "preboot": "5.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.5",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "4.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "chai": "4.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.4"
  }
}
```

my app.module.ts is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { UserComponent } from "./components/user/user.component";
import { ErrorComponent } from "./components/error/error.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        UserComponent,
        ErrorComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },

            { path: 'user', component: UserComponent },
            { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },

            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
}
```

the GIT repository is here https://github.com/dobrinsky/AngularDefault .

Please help... this is so hard to understand why is not working since everybody sais it is simple to use...

P.S. I am not using webpack. do these 2 packs require webpack to run?

UPDATE: using **npm install webpack** throws

```
NodeInvocationException: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpXsrfCookieExtractor: (?, [object Object], [object Object])
```

After this I tried:

- Uninstalling Node completely (along with any version managers / etc)
- Go to %AppData% / roaming delete any npm or npm cache folders there
- Reboot your machine, install the latest Node 6.*
- npm i -g webpack

I do not get the above warnings when installing, but and now I get:

```
Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module build failed: TypeError: loaderUtils.getOptions is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to run this command 
***webpack --config webpack.config.js***
or
***webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js*** 
after updating you package .
if it not run then you must install web pack first using this command 
***npm install --global webpack***

Comment: Used following commands and it works for me, node `node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.js` then `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js` then `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`